# How to specify/modiy target-port on a newly created app through openshift CLI?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to expose a new app created via openshift command line(oc). This is a nodeJS server listening on port=3000. However, opeshift defaults the target-port to 8080 as shown in the following service.yaml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
.............
.............
spec: 
  ports:
    - name: 8080-tcp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
.........
```

I want to be able to update targetPort via the command line. I already followed these steps, but no luck so far:

step1: `oc new-project my-new-project`

step2: `oc new-app https:\\github.org.com\my-new-app.git`

step3: `oc expose service my-new-app --target-port=3000`

`Error: **cannot use --target-port with --generator=route/v1**`

Note: I am able to access the app(i.e. port=3000) only when I manually update targetPort to 3000 in Services.yaml.

Comment: same issue with me. have to manually change it

Answer (score -1):

You didnt specify port . Try this.

oc expose service my-new-app --target-port=3000 --port=8080

Comment: Same error even after adding the port parameter error: cannot use --target-port with --generator=route/v1